# WEBUTILS in ORACLE form work fine, unless I try to use them on startup

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have an ORACLE 12c form which displays a list of files stored in the database. The form allows a user to import and export these files using webutils. It all works fine, but if I change the form to automatically export a file on startup (using exactly the same code as a user would use if they pressed the Export button, but without having the user to press anything), the form complains that it can't find webutils. What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: See the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: What exactly is "on startup"? WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE or PRE-FORM triggers? Something else?

Comment: Any way you like. I am using a WHEN-NEW_FORM_INSTANCE trigger in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since I posted this question, I ran across two sites which said that you can't call webutils via WNFI unless you use a timer. I am yet to try this at work, but it certainly sounds like the way to go.

Comment: This might be the case.  Also, (its been a long time so this might be hogwash), check the jar files that you are loading.  By default, I think forms only started with "frmweb.jar" (or something like that), so only just enough classes were loaded at start, with the rest loaded as required.  Perhaps change that to "frmall.jar" to get the lot.

(I stress, this is a from memory from a long long time ago :-))

Comment: The change worked fine. I already had been loading frmall.jar.